# Expand f and t motion to next lines

Tags: cursor-motions

Is there a way that `t{char}` and `f{char}` will continue to work in the next lines if `{char}` is not present in a given line?

I would like to avoid using `/{char}<CR>` to save 1 keystroke and to not have search highlighting, especially when I need this in combination with verbs (e.g. `dfa`, `ct.`).

Comment: You can do `d/a` to delete to the next `a` and `c/.` to delete to the next `.`. If you use `hlsearch` and don't want it when doing this operation, you can create a mapping which does your `d/` operation and then disables the highlighting (ends with `:nohlsearch`).

Comment: You could use (or study) a plugin such as https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim (with `g:clever_f_across_no_line` set to 0 and other options enabled/disabled at will).

Comment: Dahu made a plugin for this: https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic

Comment: I still think the best plugin for this is [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion)

Comment: I also made a plugin: [improvedft](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft)

Comment: Personally, I find easymotion a bit too intrusive. I do not like the automatic search highlighting in clever-f, therefore I would not choose it.  That leaves improvedft and vim-fanfingtastic. Which one is in your opinion more mature? Besides their respective (small) limitations mentioned on the website, the only thing I noticed in a quick test of both was that showcmd no longer works.

Comment: One desirable feature is to have `.` repeats remember the count rather than the number of chars consumed.  (E.g. `d4t|` `<CR>.` should find the fourth `|` no matter its column.)  fanfingtastic does this, but I'm not sure about improvedft or clever-f.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was also using [dahu/vim-fanfingtastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic) for some time and found it very helpful.  It supports semantic repeats with `.` thanks to the library [tpope/repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) which you must also install.

An alternative is [chrisbra/improvedft](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft) which does more or less the same thing.

[rhysd/clever-f.vim](https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim) has an option to enable multi-line seeking, although its primary feature is to allow **`f` to repeat** the current seek, like `;` does already.

Those all handle `;` and `,` keys as expected.

The **disadvantage** with multi-line `f` and `t` is that if you hit the wrong key, you will be taken off the current line to **somewhere unexpected** in the file.  <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> can help in those moments.  (This can be dangerous with a `c` change if you don't realise that you just swallowed a few lines, but those were only teething troubles for me.)

There are other related plugins, with slightly different approaches, such as [justinmk/vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) and [goldfeld/vim-seek](https://github.com/goldfeld/vim-seek) which prompt for **two characters**, making it easier (but still not guaranteed) to hit your target location.

And then there is [easymotion/vim-easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion).  This offers a lot of **powerful motion keys**, some of which require an extra keypress or two to confirm the target character when there are many candidates.

---

But currently I'm using a home grown solution.  I [worked with](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/issues/160) the author of EasyMotion to make `f` and `t` **flash count markers** over all the matching characters ahead of you.

[image]

This acts as a natural **count assistant** for vanilla vim motions.  When you try to move somewhere with `fx` but then discover there are more `x`s in the way than you thought, you can read the number that flashed over the character you were aiming for, and then do `[count];` to jump there.

You can find the [branch here](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/tree/feature-flash-motions).  Be sure to read the section *Add helpful hinting* to set up the key mappings.

However for `c` change operations, it is still preferable to **get it right the first time**.  In those cases I recommend spending an extra keystroke in `v` Visual mode, or using one of EasyMotion's guaranteed jumps.

Answer (score 2):

there is a plugin that does what you seem to be wanting, as stated by VanLaser.

https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic

It now requires the repeat plugin to work properly, so you will need that too:

https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat

Comment: You should mention the other alternatives as well

Comment: Wasn't me :) I mentioned https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim

Answer (score 0):

In spacemacs you can use `SPC j w {first-char-of-word}`.

Although this is different, it has replaced my need for `ft` across lines. What I do now is use `ft` for same line searches, and `SPC j w` for anything else.

As a bonus, you can jump to lines in other visible buffers too! Really convenient for split-window programming.

Comment: Spacemacs? As in the emacs distribution? I'm not sure how that really qualifies as an answer on [vi.se]…

Comment: Actually you are right. I thought I was on [emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/). That said, this answer would've helped me as I frequent [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) as a spacemacs user.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that spacemacs [supports vim bindings](https://www.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#vim), which is why I find myself in this forum often.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, so I'm not sure if a spacemacs specific mapping is on-topic (it's implementation could be, if it were done with a vi mapping or vimscript or similar).