# How to "find" or "till" a bigram?

Tags: cursor-movement, find

I have to do a lot of hopping in lines.

Often times I want to hop to a `t` in a line, and promptly press `ft`, only to discover that I have to do it 7 times before I can actually make it to my destination.

I'm trying to think of ways to eliminate this time waster. Is there a way to find a bigram instead, so `fts` would hop to `ts` in a line?

Comment: how about using `/ts<CR>` it will be four keys instead of three...

Comment: I use easymotion too for that problem, but i just wanted to hint, you can repeat the `f` command with `;`. And also use a count for that, for example, you press `ft`, then see that you have do do 6 more jumps, you can press `6;`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo `;` for me was remapped to `:`. Perhaps its time to remap that.

Answer (score 5):

The [sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) plugin provides that functionality.

By default, it's bound to the `s` key, so you would need to use `sts` for your example.  The documentation also gives [example](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak#how-can-i-replace-f-with-sneak) mappings to put sneak's functionality on the `f` family of keys or to enhance the standard 1-character searches with some of sneak's other improvements.

Answer (score 3):

The [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin also provides functionality like that. 
Easymotion is considered to be larger with more features, both come highly recommended. Maybe someone needs to write a review of both, while checking them out...

Comment: Sneak & Easymotion have a quite different principle. Sneak only provides an 'improved' version of `f` with two instead of 1 characters. While easymotion highlights every occurence and let you jump directly with enumerations. Easymotion has this functionality also for search, and can even search and jump over multiple splits. But Sneak is more flexible, allowing you to use it in a normal command chaining. F. E. `d2<sneak>ts` is perfectly fine while `d2<easymotion>ts` won't work. Also sneak is repeatable with `;`. (Feel free to correct me, if it is also possible with easymotion)

Comment: esaymotion does have bigram movements like sneak, movements are also repeatable, but use the `.` instead of `;`. Which one is "right" or "better" is of course a matter of debate.

Comment: Do you mean, easymotion has a bigram movement, which like sneak does automatically select the first match ? I only know of the `easymotion-overwin-f2` function, which enumerates all matches. Also can't repeat the `easymotion-overwin-f2` function with `.` what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the plugins mentions, there are several other plugins available, that extend the `f` and `t` motions. Among there are [clever-f](https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim), [vim-fanfingtastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic) and my own [ft-improved](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft).

At least for my plugin I can tell you, that you can configure it, to check for several following characters. You have to set `:let g:ft_improved_multichars = 1` in your vimrc for that.

Also you might be interested in this [similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/expand-f-and-t-motion-to-next-lines)