# Multiline search like with f and F

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode

I'm using vim for C programming and I have a question about jumping to the next/previous character. I can use <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> to jump to the next or previous character correspondingly. But this does not work with multiline.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to jump to the previous `{` or next `}` to quickly get to the function signature I'm currently looking at.

Comment: If you are specifically interested in moving to `{` and `}`, this would be `[[` and `][`. Have a look at [`:h 29.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_29.txt.html#29.3), paragraph *MOVING IN CODE BLOCKS*. Also [this answer by me](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/how-to-delete-entire-function-definition-c-style/17775#17775) gives some more context about them.

Comment: If you want that `fFtT` are not restricted to the current line, there are several plugins which provide this and additional functionality: [vim-fanfingtastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic), [improvedft](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft), [vim-extended-ft](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-extended-ft), [clever-f.vim](https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim) and probably more.

Comment: Some other popular plugins related to moving across lines without using `/?` are [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) and [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak).

Comment: @Hotschke Very cool, thanks. Works exactly as desired!

Comment: You are welcome. However, your actual question is a duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/jumping-to-start-end-of-function-definition-in-c. Your title is an XY problem even though  it is a valid request. Your actual movement question is about moving to the beginning and end of a C function which you wisely added to the body of the question. But also the question asked in the title exists already: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/expand-f-and-t-motion-to-next-lines. Therefore I am in favour of marking this question as a duplicate.